# It protects you

Tags: riddle

> You can touch it.
>
> You can feel it.
>
> You can smell it.
>
> It protects you.

**Who am I?**

Comment: Barring some ingenious hidden meaning cunningly embedded in the puzzle somehow, this is probably going to be too broad.

Comment: Based on the edit history that last line should read "What is IT?" And here I thought I was onto something.

Comment: Skin, hair, shoes, shocks to name a few, OP might want to narrow it down a bit

Answer (score 3):

Going to really stretch here: "IT" must be...

> A condom.

You can touch it.

> Oh yes you can.

You can feel it.

> Unfortunately, yeah. Kinda spoils the whole vibe, but what's one gonna do?

You can smell it.

> Technically *yeah*, but trust me, there is very little upside in doing so. These buddies are not made for smelling if you know what I mean.

It protects you

> Literally the whole point of these things, so... check.

Stay safe, everyone! And for the minors on this site (if any), I do so apologise.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be

> Your skin?

The line about smell might be a bit of a stretch, but it fits the other criteria perfectly imho. Additionally,

> You can't just touch and feel it, you can even touch and feel **with** it

Answer (score 0):

It might be

> Clothes

Because

> You can feel, smell and touch clothes, and they protect you from cold weather and other types of damage like scratches.

Answer (score 0):

Well, already many answers are there. Here is a try

> It could be **sweat**

As

> One can touch, feel and smell one's sweat and also the main intended feature of sweating is to protect.